# Java Generic Design Validity

Tags: java, generics

I have the following hierarchy :

```
abstract class customType<E extends Number>
class customInteger extends customType<Integer>
class customFloat extends customType<Float>
```

to declare a LinkedList which accepts both customInteger and customFloat

```
List<customType<Number>> items = new LinkedList<customType<Number>>();
```

is this approach valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customType<Number>` is unrelated to `customType<Integer>`
So if you plan to add `Integer` or `Float` in `items` then this is not valid.
You can try the following:

`List<CustomType<?>> items = new LinkedList<CustomType<?>>();`

Use this as the collection for your items. To add the items you should use an auxiliary method as follows:

```
public static void addItemToList(List<? super CustomType<?>> l, CustomType<? extends Number> o){  
        l.add(o);  
}
```

Then you can add to the list:

```
CustomFloat f = new CustomFloat();  
CustomInteger i = new CustomInteger();  
process(items, i);    
process(items, f);
```

Comment: To put it explicityly, if `A extends B`, then `List<A>` **does not** extend `List<B>` (or whatever Generic class you use).

Comment: I need two classes one has a Float data field and the other one has Integer data field and both classes have String data field. They should be storable in same collection instance

Comment: Could you give an example? Like on my first post.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Cratylus, `customType<Number>`, `customType<Float>`, and `customType<Integer>` are three unrelated types, so this is not going to work. However, you can use `List<customType<?>>` as the type for `items`. Both `customType<Float>` and `customType<Integer>` are subtypes of `customType<?>` (which means "any `customType`, no matter what generic parameter value it has), and can thus be inserted into the collection.

Note that the Java convention is to start type names with an uppercase letter, so you should use the names `CustomType`, `CustomInteger`, and `CustomFloat`.